# Is there a common RDF property indicating a compatible revision of a class?

Tags: rdf, rdfs

I'm dealing with a schema migration of RDF data where I want to generically indicate that a given class is the new version of an old class, but that instances of that old class are also instances of the new class. For classes `?oldClass` and `?newClass`, I'd want to make a statement like:

```
?oldClass :isAlso ?newClass .
```

So, if we had an instance `ex:a` like this:

```
ex:a rdf:type ex:C1 .
```

and had a new version of `ex:C1`, `ex:C2`, then

```
ex:C1 :isAlso ex:C2 .
# implies
ex:a rdf:type ex:C2 .
```

but it's not true that

```
ex:a1 rdf:type ex:C2 .
```

implies

```
ex:a1 rdf:type ex:C1 .
```

I could add additional triples `?x rdf:type ex:C2` triples for every `?x rdf:type ex:C1` triple, but I don't want to add all of these additional triples since I can do the inference/query on the fly pretty cheaply and storing this info efficiently is a priority. I'd like to use a well-known property if possible.

I've considered and rejected:

- `owl:equivalentClass`: the relationship I want is not reflexive
- `rdfs:subClassOf`: the relationship I want does not extend to subclasses of the old class.

Do I just need to define a new property, `:isAlso` with the semantics I describe? I prefer to use something that is already being generally used so the statements I generate are properly interpreted by existing tools.

Comment: A bit confusing, so let me ask for clarification: stick to your example `C2` is the new version of `C1`? Does this mean any instance of `C1` becomes an instance of `C2` in your data? Or is the definition of `C2` different such that we cannot say this holds for all instances of `C1` be default?

Comment: I'm also wondering what you mean by "define a new property with the semantics I describe" - the main issue is that you cannot define any property with some special kind of inference support beyond what you have in RDFS. We have to live with `rdfs:subClassOf` and `rdfs:subPropertyOf` - at least in RDFS that's all we have (end domain/range of course) - indeed, querying via SPARQL you can make based on any new property if you want, that's trivial

Comment: @UninformedUser, I'm not constrained to RDFS. What I have in mind is that there could be a schema that, although I don't know about it, defines rules that entail triples in the way I describe.

Comment: I think I confused myself: I'm mapping RDF to classes in Python where I define a new class rather than edit the old one for a new version of the RDF class. I'm given the new Python class, get the corresp. RDF class, and query for instances. I don't want to get sub-classes of the old *Python* class when I query, but that's actually just up to my mapping. I'll remove the point about instances of sub-classes from my question.

Comment: Why don't you just use Dublin Core's `dcterms:isReplacedBy` (http://purl.org/dc/terms/isReplacedBy) or inv. `dcterms:replaces`, `ex:C2 dcterms:replaces ex:C1`? Then you can just knock up a CONSTRUCT statement so that every C@ is a C! on that basis but not the inverse

Comment: @NicholasCar, the new version isn't necessarily a replacement. The new version may be recommended but it's possible that use of the old version, even creating new instances, is still OK.

Comment: What about PAV (https://pav-ontology.github.io/pav/) if you need more detailed properties? That's got `pav:hasCurrentVersion`, `pav:hasEarlierVersion`, generic `pav:hasVersion` etc.: all the versioning skill you might expect of something like Git. Then you can just link a `CONSTRUCT` to those properties to actually generate the instance typing. We (Australian Govt. and related) use PAV a fair bit.